# Возвращение значения переменной C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток . У меня есть такой скрипт управления объектом и есть скрипт коллизии . При  коллизии скрипт передаёт  СollisionInd = true в этот скрипт(скрипт управления)и в этом скрипте(управления ) изменяется вектор движения объекта. 
Но так как СollisionInd = true  при следующей коллизии скрипт не срабатывает 
.

Как мне вернуть значение в public bool СollisionInd  или fallse или null?

Пробовал return СollisionInd = false но видимо что то не понимаю.

```
using UnityEngine;

 public class move2 : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool СollisionInd ;
public float DirX, DirY;
private bool CollisionTriger;
void Start()
{

}
 void Update()
{
    CollisionTriger = СollisionInd;

    transform.Translate(new Vector2(1+ DirX, 1 + DirY) * Time.deltaTime);

   if (CollisionTriger == true)
      // Debug.Log("коллизия!");
    {
       if (DirX == 0 && DirY == 0)
       {
           Debug.Log("Сработал отскок аправо вниз !");
           DirY = -2;
          // СollisionInd = false;
          //return СollisionInd = false;
       }
       else if ((DirX == 0) && (DirY < 0))
       {
           Debug.Log("Сработал отскок вправо вверх!");
           DirX = -2;

       }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void Update()
        {
            CollisionTriger = СollisionInd;

            transform.Translate(new Vector2(1 + DirX, 1 + DirY) * Time.deltaTime);

            if (CollisionTriger == true)
                // Debug.Log("коллизия!");
            {
                if (DirX == 0 && DirY == 0)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Сработал отскок аправо вниз !");
                    DirY = -2;
                    // СollisionInd = false;
                    //return СollisionInd = false;
                }
                else if ((DirX == 0) && (DirY < 0))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Сработал отскок вправо вверх!");
                    DirX = -2;

                }

                СollisionInd = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: не работает скорее всего потаму что второй раз не выполняется условие `if (DirX == 0 && DirY == 0)`